# Entity Framework OrderBy().Where() expression

Tags: entity-framework, linq, sql-order-by, where-clause

I've been using Entity Framework for a little while now with no issues, until i stumbled upon a curly one....well it is for me atleast anyway. I have searched the internet and cannot find anything related to this but i assume it is merely because i am asking the wrong question. So here goes...

```
query= query.OrderByDescending(u => u.DateCreated);
```

This is simple and works fine. However the table being queried is for workflow and there are 4 date columns, `CreatedDate`, `EstimatedDate`, `RevisedDate` and `ActualDate`. At the beginning of the workflow for this element the `CreatedDate` will and all the other date columns will be `NULL`. As the element progresses through workflow the subsequent dates will be filled.

So what i am trying to achieve is this, i don't want any grouping, i just want the date to be used for `OrderBy()` to be the last date in the workflow.

I can achieve this by adding another column to my table called `FilterDate` which is used solely for sorting and gets updated with the appropriate date based upon workflow, however this is adding another column to my table just because I can't come up with a smart method of achieving this.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the last date in the workflow" in this sentence "i don't want any grouping, i just want the date to be used for OrderBy() to be the last date in the workflow"?

Comment: Apologies if i didn't explain myself correctly but hopefully this makes more sense. The workflow i am speaking about is for a Work Order for completing a job. When the Work Order is first created all Date fields will be NULL except for the CreatedDate. So when there is a list of all the Work Orders, i want this particalur work order to be ordered within the list based upon its CreatedDate. Once a contractor accepts the job they will propose a date, this will be the EstimatedDate.

Comment: At this stage i want this particular Work Order to be ordered in the list based upon its EstimatedDate, rather than its CreatedDate. Again, at a later stage, the contractor may propose a new date, hence the RevisedDate and then finally once the work is completed i want the Work Order to be ordered in the list of Work Orders based upon its ActualDate.

Comment: As i intially said, i can create an extra date column for the WorkOrder where i just put the most recent date in the work flow into this column so that i can just filter by this date column and will always return the work orders based on their most recent date in the workflow. But, this is an extra column in a table solely for the purpose of filtering.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but this should be what you're looking for, assuming that ActualDate (if populated) is always >= RevisedDate >= EstimatedDate => CreatedDate:

```
query= query.OrderByDescending(u => u.ActualDate.HasValue
    ? u.ActualDate.Value
    : u.RevisedDate.HasValue
    ? u.RevisedDate.Value
    : u.EstimatedDate.HasValue
    ? u.EstimatedDate.Value
    : u.CreatedDate);
```

This will order by whichever date is available preferencing the Actual over Revised over Estimated and defaulting to the Created.

This doesn't handle if it's possible that a RevisedDate could be after an ActualDate for instance. If the row had an RevisedDate of 2020-12-02 and an ActualDate of 2020-11-25, this query would be using the ActualDate for comparison, not the later RevisedDate.

Comment: The dates in the work flow are always in order as you have assumed. I will test this method shortly and see how it goes. I am not familiar with the ? in a query so will need to learn more about this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly then you don't need to add an extra column to your table.
You just need to add a `[NotMapped]` decorated property to your object, because that property won't be saved in the database.

```cs
[NotMapped]
public DateTime FilteringDate
{
    get
    {
        if (ActualDate.HasValue) return (DateTime)ActualDate;
        else if (RevisedDate.HasValue) return (DateTime)RevisedDate;
        else if (EstimatedDate.HasValue) return (DateTime)EstimatedDate;
        else return CreatedDate;
    }
}
```

usage

```cs
query = query.OrderByDescending(u => u.FilteringDate);
```